# How to change a parameter to accept variables in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm just starting to learn iOS Development and i'm watching a slightly outdated video on functions. In the video based on swift 2 the instructor did

**Ex.**

```
func example(var a: Int){


}
```

In swift 3, you can not do this to change the argument passed to a variable, does anyone know how I could do this in the current syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use var like this in swift 3.0 with function parameter.

```
func example(a: Int){
    var a = a
}
```

You can read more about this here [SE-0003](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md#impact-on-existing-code)

Answer (score 0):

```
func example(a: Int){ // You doen't need to write var for parameters

}
```

Comment: he won't be able to change it then, you didn't understand the question

Comment: solution `(a: inout Int)`